# windows 7 photo viewer - lags when closing

Tags: windows-7, lag

I just assembled a new PC with AMD Ryzen 5 and I am having some troubles with default photo viewer. I've read some people experiences similar problem, but the difference is that my viewer freezes the entire system for ~1s every time it closes. It runs smoothly while opening and using it, then it lags at closing.

I have checked coloring profiles for the monitors, but there is none "calibrated" as people suggested in other topics I have read.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you delete/remove any system file from "C:\Windows\System32\spool"?

Comment: Adjusting the coloring profile by calibrating your monitor isn't going to solve a I/O latency issue.

Comment: Nothing was deleted, I have just installed the system 2 days ago. I'm wondering what could be the cause, apparently it lags when closing this particular app.

Comment: Update: Media Player Classic lags aswell. @Ramhound you said about I/O latency, so copied a sample to SSD (all the files was stored in HDD) and tried it out. The result seems to be the same - not a problem to copy, open, manage files, but only when closing. Both photo viewer and Media Player Classic.